# How to externalise repeated SOAP response attributes in mule dataweave?

Tags: soap, mule, integration, dataweave, soapheader

I am constructing a SOAP response in Dataweave. Certain components (ESBHeader) of the response are repeated in multiple flows. I also need to set the Status code and message per request.

I need a generic/common way of loading these repeated lines into a common dwl file for code optimisation. How do I do it?

**Example Response Message1 of flow1**

```
{
        ns1#ResponseMsg1: {
            ns0#ESBHeader: {
                ns0#InitialContext @(CreationTime: flowVars.req.ResponseMsg1.ESBHeader.InitialContext.@CreationTime, TrackingID: flowVars.req.ResponseMsg1.ESBHeader.InitialContext.@TrackingID): {
                    ns0#Actor @(Component: flowVars.req.ResponseMsg1.ESBHeader.InitialContext.Actor.@Component , Operation: flowVars.req.ResponseMsg1.ESBHeader.InitialContext.Actor.@Operation): null
                },
                ns0#MessageContext  : {
                    ns0#Actor @(Component: flowVars.req.ResponseMsg1.ESBHeader.MessageContext.Actor.@Component  , Operation: flowVars.req.ResponseMsg1.ESBHeader.MessageContext.Actor.@Operation): null
                },
                ns0#Status: {
                    ns0#Code: "Success",
                    ns0#Message: ""
                }
            },
            ns1#var1: flowVars.var1
        }
    }
```

**Example Response Message2 of flow2**

```
{
        ns1#ResponseMsg2: {
            ns0#ESBHeader: {
                ns0#InitialContext @(CreationTime: flowVars.req.ResponseMsg2.ESBHeader.InitialContext.@CreationTime, TrackingID: flowVars.req.ResponseMsg2.ESBHeader.InitialContext.@TrackingID): {
                    ns0#Actor @(Component: flowVars.req.ResponseMsg2.ESBHeader.InitialContext.Actor.@Component , Operation: flowVars.req.ResponseMsg2.ESBHeader.InitialContext.Actor.@Operation): null
                },
                ns0#MessageContext  : {
                    ns0#Actor @(Component: flowVars.req.ResponseMsg2.ESBHeader.MessageContext.Actor.@Component  , Operation: flowVars.req.ResponseMsg2.ESBHeader.MessageContext.Actor.@Operation): null
                },
                ns0#Status: {
                    ns0#Code: "Failure",
                    ns0#Message: ""
                }
            },
            ns1#var1: flowVars.var1,
            ns1#var2: flowVars.x.var2
        }
    }
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Depends on if you're using Mule 3 or Mule 4

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mule 4 it is easy to create and import a [DataWeave module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/dataweave-create-module).

In Mule 3 there is a similar method but it is not really supported and you could run into some issues. From your script it looks like Mule 3. This [blog post](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/training-dev/how-to-reuse-dataweave-code/) explains the method.